# Get-credential command get WinError 10060 - A connection attempt failed

Tags: azure-container-service

After successfull created the resource group and the cluster ( I checked by portal azure) and succesfully installed azure cli 2.0 on powershell,
when i launch

```
az acs kubernetes get-credentials -g my-group -n my-name
```

I always get the error in the title. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: new second paragraph.

The az acs cli tries to smartly handle ssh private keys for you. It doesn't always work perfectly. Did you create the cluster using the az cli or portal or powershell?  My best guess is that you have don't have the right ssh private key being loaded. If the az acs cli created the ssh key for you it should have put it somewhere it can find it, but if it isn't working you can point the cli to the correct private key using the flag `--ssh-key-file`.

So apparently a bug was introduced in az acs kubernetes get-credentials in 2.0.4  of the az cli a fix has been checked in and is in 2.0.5. It is very possible this is your issue. So I'd update the az acs module and retry the command.